# How to create mnemonic with 13th/25th

Tags: metamask, myetherwallet, password, mnemonic, passphrase

How can I create the wallet that has a mnemonic with an extra word that I choose? I tried doing that with MyEtherWallet however when I create it with MEW I don't get the private key. I'd like to get the private key so that I can add it to MetaMask.